# SQL between not returning all results

Tags: mysql, between

I have this simple Mysql query

```
select *
from reportings
where findcampaign = 1 and
      is_click = 1 and
      created_at BETWEEN date(2016-11-01) AND date(2016-12-31)
```

This should return all the rows where findcampaign = 1 and is_click is = 1 where the created_at dates are between 2016-11-01 and 2016-12-31.

running `select * from reportings where findcampaign = 1 and is_click = 1`

gives me 12 rows

[image]

The image shows that those reportings are all between those dates, so I should get 12 rows. Is this the correct way to get the between date and date from the database even though my created_at has a timestamp value. Or would I need to append a time to the dates?

Comment: Try `BETWEEN '2016-11-01' AND '2016-12-31'` note the single quotes

Comment: 2016-11-01 is *2004* - subtraction of 3 ints, quote it if its a date string.

Comment: Try enclosing the dates between single quotes, something like `date('2016-11-01')` (the same for the other).

Comment: I'm surprised the query even runs...

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen New definition of _Does not return all_ is obviously _dont work at all_

Comment: Its Dev burnout I tell you, such a simple mistake :/

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen `2016-11-01` expression can be interpreted as 2 subtractions and MySQL can convert the resulting number to a date, however, that will not be the expected date limit, hence there will not be any records returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should put quotes for date

```
select *
from reportings
where findcampaign = 1 and
      is_click = 1 and
      created_at BETWEEN date('2016-11-01') AND date('2016-12-31')
```

Comment: You don't even need to wrap the quoted dates with `date()`.  Just use `BETWEEN '2016-11-01' AND '2016-12-31'`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen For string its okay. but mentioning date() here ,it need to be quoted. atleast for mysql.

Comment: Why use a `date` function with argument which itself is date only

Answer (score 2):

You are asking about predicates where you're comparing dates to columns with `datetime` data. If you put the dates in single quotes, as mentioned, then it should work, but it is often best to be more explicit about what is going on since `BETWEEN` when working with dates can be confusing.

I recommend:

```
select *
from reportings
where findcampaign = 1 and
      is_click = 1 and
      created_at >= '2016-11-01 00:00:00' and
      created_at <= '2016-12-31 00:00:00';
```

This condition is the same as the one in your query, and makes it very clear that all values for `created_at` on 31 December 2016 will be excluded, from `2016-12-31 00:00:01` through `2016-12-31 23:59:59`.

You may wish to include 31 Dec 2016, in which case you would change the second date to `2017-01-01 00:00:00`

Comment: And, I can see that there are no 31 Dec dates in the dataset, just think this is good practice for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

hey just little syntax error buddy. Single inverted comma needed in date

try this

```
select * from reportings where findcampaign = 1 and is_click = 1 and created_at BETWEEN date('2016-11-01') AND date('2016-12-31')
```